# Value restriction: The type 'bar' has been inferred to have generic type

Tags: f#

In the snippet below, I cannot see why I have to compose `f` and `g` the way function `foo` does and why it does not work the way function `bar` tries to do it.

```
let f a b = a,b
let g (a : 'a) (b : 'a) = a

let (>!) f1 f2 =
    fun a b ->
        let (x,y) = f1 a b
        f2 x y

let foo = fun a b -> (f >! g) a b
let bar = f >! g
```

Can anyone explain to me, why `bar` is not working? Given that `foo` also has generic type, it makes no sense to me.

Comment: You added a restriction that  g's arguments have the same type, while `f` accepts two different types

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Without the annotations on the args of ``g``, the infered type is ``'a -> 'b -> 'a``. So I cannot see why that changes things, given that now it is ``'a -> 'a -> 'a``.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`foo` is a function, while `bar` is a value. Yes, it's a value of a function type, but still a value. There is a subtle difference there.

The F# compiler can "see" that `foo` is a function, because it sees the `fun ->` right after `let`.

Your `bar`, on the other hand, is a true value - a result obtained by invoking a different function (the operator `>!`). F# has a rule (known as "value restriction") saying (in everyday terms) that values (unlike functions) cannot have generic types, unless generic arguments are specified explicitly, thus effectively making it a "type function". (it's a bit more complicated than that, read the links below for the full picture)

This is not specific to F#, though - other non-pure variants of ML have this as well. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/) is a discussion of this rule for F#, and [here's](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction) a discussion for SML.

Comment: Does that not hint that something is wrong? Are functions not first class citizens in the end? The return value of ``>!`` is a function just as the definition of ``foo`` is a function.

Comment: Read the links I provided.

Comment: In simple terms though, this is not a matter of functions being first class, but a matter of syntax and definitions. There are other similar examples: functions defined in modules are different from those defined on static classes, which are different from those defined in a local context. Another example - even though functions are "values", their genericity isn't included - i.e. you can't pass around a generic function without instantiating it.

Comment: From the provided link I finally understand what it is about. F# does not guarantee that functions are side effect free and return immutable objects. Hence, the compiler has to prevent this from working as otherwise there would be pathological cases, which truly should not work. This also explains to me, why the same approach works in haskell, while it does not in F# (ML). Thanks a lot for the insights.