# Why does F# have two types of explicit type declarations?

Tags: f#

After playing around with Idris I've become a huge fan of using **explicit types** to strengthen the declarative-self-documentation of my F# programs by more often writing the types explicitly on my functions and by using type aliases.

Defining my functions with **explicit types** has made me (re-)discover that F# actually has two styles of explicit typing for functions. There is the standard let function style using `:` and there is the lambda functions using `->`.

For example

```
// explicitly typed function using the classical let ':' style
let OK1 (content : string) (context : Context) : Async<Context option> =
    { context with Response = { Content = content; StatusCode = 200 } }
    |> Some
    |> async.Return
// explicitly typed function using the '->' style
let OK2 : string -> Context -> Async<Context option> = fun content context ->
    { context with Response = { Content = content; StatusCode = 200 } }
    |> Some
    |> async.Return
```

The nice thing about the `->` style is that I can define type aliases such as

```
// type alias defining a webpart
type WebPart = Context -> Async<Context option>
// using the type alias in the declaration of an explicitly typed function
let OK2 : string -> WebPart = fun content context ->
    { context with Response = { Content = content; StatusCode = 200 } }
    |> Some
    |> async.Return
```

*I don't think it's possible to declare and use the same type alias with the `:` style...?*

I am puzzled why F# has two styles of declaring explicit types on functions. Is it some sort of .Net limitation? or does it have some special purpose? **Why not just define all explicit types with `->` instead of `:`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather use the term *type annotation* here instead of "explicit type declaration". The latter suggests there's more going on than there really is - type annotations are there just to guide the compiler (and sometimes the programmer), nothing more.

There are no "two styles" here. There's just one style. You have a value you want to annotate, you follow it with a `:` and the type signature. `->` is just part of a function type name.

```
let OK2 : string -> Context -> Async<Context option> = fun content context ->
    ...
```

In the snippet above, you have a `let` binding `OK2`, you annotate it with type `string -> Context -> Async<Context option>` and you provide a value for it - which just happens to be a function. Compare a binding for a simple value, this is exactly the same syntax:

```
let simpleValue : int = 42
```

This is however not a particularly convenient way of thinking about functions. Rather than values, it's more convenient to think about them as entities that take some arguments and return a result. And this is what the shorthand declaration captures. But it's not an entirely different, separate style as you seem to alude, otherwise this wouldn't be possible:

```
let OK2 (content: string): Context -> Async<Context option> = fun context ->
    ...
```

You're right in that you can't use the `WebPart` alias here. Which shouldn't be surprising considering that you no longer have a value of the aliased type here.

I agree with you that there is value in using function type aliases in that way. It can make your functions appear more uniform at the first glance, which improves readability and discoverability of your API - but in the same time, you pay the price by making the implementation of the individual functions more convoluted. There's always a trade-off involved.

Answer (score 1):

The two options are completely equivalent, they mean exactly the same thing, are compiled in exactly the same way. The first option exists as sort of a shortcut. Compare the two:

```
let f = fun a b -> a + b
let f a b = a + b
```

The second one is shorter and reads easier.

Comment: I agree for the presented case. Though the example seems to have nothing to do with explicit types. I am mostly interested in why the explicit type definitions are different between the lambda style and the 'normal' style. It seems with the 'normal' style you loose the ability to  use type aliases such as `type WebPart = Context -> Async<Context option>` in your explicit type declarations.

Comment: Compare to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394254/value-restriction-the-type-bar-has-been-inferred-to-have-generic-type . In that light, the statement "The two options are completely equivalent" might not hold. Not sure, though.

Comment: Yes, the notion does hold in that context. `foo` is a regular function, its definition is equivalent to `let foo a b = ...`, but `bar` is different.

Comment: @BitTickler the statement does hold if `f` is declared directly as `fun ...` or `function ...`. Value restriction only comes into play when the expression for `f` is not directly an anonymous function, because only then there is a risk of side-effects.