# Trouble understanding type inference when returning function from function in FSharp

Tags: f#

I'm using log4net in my F# application, and wanted to make logging more idiomatic F# by creating a few functions.

For warnings I created the following function:

```
let log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("foo")
let warn format = Printf.ksprintf log.Warn format
```

This works pretty well, and I can do:

```
warn "This is a warning"
// and
warn "The value of my string is %s" someString
```

However I wanted to make this more generic and make it possible to pass in the logger I wanted. Thus I wrapped the function in another function that can take an ILog as parameter:

```
let getWarn (logger: log4net.ILog) =
    fun format -> Printf.ksprintf logger.Warn format
```

and I also tried:

```
let getWarn (logger: log4net.ILog) format =
    Printf.ksprintf logger.Warn format
```

When I now use it like this:

```
let warn = getWarn log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("bar")
warn "This is a warning"
```

This works, however when I do:

```
warn "The value of my string is %s" someString
```

I get a compiler error saying `"The value is not a function and cannot be applied"`
If I remove the first warn statement, it works.

So I guess that the compiler infers the type based on the first statement where I use `warn`, and therefore I need to use it the same way always.

But why is this not the case in my first example where I use the `warn` function directly and not through `getWarn`?

Comment: Try rewriting your `getWarn` function like this: `let getWarn (logger: log4net.ILog) format = Printf.ksprintf logger.Warn format`. Does that let the compiler's type inference figure out what you're going for? If so, then you're hitting some kind of issue where it can figure out an argument's type in a classic function declaration, but not when that same argument is in a lambda expression.

Comment: No, same result I'm affraid

Comment: Try forward piping into warn.

Comment: What type does your IDE show you when you hover over the `format` parameter of your `getWarn` function? Is it a `StringFormat<'T,'Result>`? And what are the types you're seeing for the `warn` and `getWarn` versions of your function?

Comment: @munn `warn: StringFormat<'a,unit> -> 'a`, `getWarn: ILog -> StringFormat<'a,unit> -> 'a` and if I supply `format` to the getWarn function, it gets the type of `'a`

Comment: @munn My previous comment was wrong about the type of format. It should be: `StringFormat<'a,unit>`

Comment: I wonder if the fact that you're passing a C# method (`logger.Warn`) to `ksprintf` is making it harder for type inference. What happens if you write an F# wrapper around the log4net method: `let wrappedWarn (logger:log4net.ILog) s = logger.Warn(s)`, and then `let getWarn (logger:log4net.ILog) fmt = Printf.ksprintf (wrappedWarn logger) fmt`? Does that help the type inference get it right?

Comment: No, still the same..

Comment: Why not write a single function that takes all the arguments you want, and then use partial application? F# functions are already curried, so they are already functions that take a single argument and return new functions, and so on...

Comment: @MarkSeemann Well, two reasons. 1. i want to understand what is going on here. 2. My actual code is somewhat different. I want to return a record like this: `{ err; warn; info; debug }` and then use pattern matching to get the loggeres I want. So it becomes: `let { err = err; warn = warn } = logger log` and the use it like this `warn "Some warning"` or `warn "The value of my string is: %s" myString` But there might be easier ways to achieve this?

Comment: @NilsMagneLunde Not sure that I follow, but I wrote about logging in F# here: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/11/30/to-log-or-not-to-log

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thanks, will read that post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [value restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394254/value-restriction-the-type-bar-has-been-inferred-to-have-generic-type/39395427#39395427).

When you declare `warn` as a plain function, it's just a generic function, no fuss. But when you declare it without parameters, it becomes a *value* (it's a value of function type, but still a value; there is a subtle difference), and so is subject to value restriction, which in a nutshell says that values cannot be generic.

Try removing all usages of `warn` (not just the first one). You'll get the compiler complain about this: `Value restriction. The value 'warn' has been inferred to have generic type`. Follow the link at the top for more discussion of this.

Of course this is a bit too strong, so F# has a little relaxation of this rule: if the value is used in the vicinity of its declaration, the compiler will fix generic arguments based on the usage. This is why it works with the first usage, but not with the second. You understood that part correctly.

One workaround would be to add explicit arguments, thus making `warn` a "declared function", not "value of function type". Try this:

```
let warn() = getWarn log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("bar")
```

Another workaround (which is really the same thing - see below) is to declare the generic argument explicitly, and also add a type annotation:

```
let warn<'a> : StringFormat<'a, unit> -> 'a = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("bar")
```

The type annotation is necessary in this case, because otherwise the compiler doesn't know how the generic argument relates to the value type.

This way, you can use it just as if it was a true generic value:

```
warn "This is a warning"
warn "The value of my string is %s" someString
```

But there is a catch: this trick is really the same as adding a unit parameter (the previous workaround, above). Behind the scenes, the compiler will emit this definition as a true declared generic function and give it a single `unit` argument. The implication of this (as well as the previous workaround) is that every time you use `warn`, it gets invoked - i.e. every time you call `warn`, you call `getWarn` and `GetLogger`, too. In this particular example, this is probably ok, but if you're doing some significant work before producing the return function, that work will get re-done on every call.

And this points us to a deeper problem with your approach: you're trying to pass around functions without losing their genericity. Can't do that. Can't have a function value, return it from a function or pass it to a function, and still have it remain generic. Try this:

```
let mapTuple f (a,b) = (f a, f b)
let makeList x = [x]

mapTuple makeList (1, "abc")
```

Instinctively one would expect this to work and produce a tuple of lists - `( [1], ["abc"] )`, right? Well, it doesn't work like this. When you declare `mapTuple f (a,b)`, that `f` parameter has to be *of some particular type*. It can't be of an open generic type, so that you could apply it to `a` and `b` even if they're of different types. Instead, the inference works the other way: since `f` is of one type, thinks the compiler, and it gets applied to both `a` and `b`, then `a` and `b` must be of the same type. And so the signature gets inferred to `mapTuple: ('a -> 'b) -> 'a*'a -> 'b*'b`.

So the bottom line is, if you just want to produce a `warn` function, just give it a parameter and you'll be fine. However, if you want to produce two at once (as you mentioned in the comments), you're out of luck: they would have to end up being of the same type and you can't call them as generic functions after they're produced.

If you want to have a function that returns a function (or several) without losing its genericity, you'll have to return an interface. Member functions on interfaces can be generic independently of the genericity of the interface itself:

```
type loggers =
    abstract member warn: Printf.StringFormat<'a, unit> -> 'a
    abstract member err: Printf.StringFormat<'a, unit> -> 'a

let getLoggers (log: log4net.ILog) = 
  { new loggers with
    member this.warn format = Printf.ksprintf log.Warn format
    member this.err format = Printf.ksprintf log.Error format }

let logs = getLoggers (log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Log"))

logs.warn "This is a warning"
logs.warn "Something is wrong: %s" someString
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! Now I understand why the compiler is behaving like this, and based on this knowledge I can find better ways to solve my logger problem.

Comment: Thanks for giving the best explanation of value restriction I've seen yet! I feel like I actually understand it now. Have 200 rep as a thank-you! (In 24 hours -- the system won't let me award the bounty I just posted until at least 24 hours have passed.)

Comment: @rmunn, thank you for the high praise, I don't think it was really that deserved :-)

Comment: To add methods with more parameters, do e.g. `abstract member Exnf: exn -> StringFormat<'h, unit> -> 'h` and `member x.Exnf exn format = Printf.ksprintf (fun title -> session.LogException(title, exn)) format` (This is a snippet from my implementation for a difference logging library, so change it as needed.)